# Tag Badge Not Aligned With Normal Badge

Tags: feature-request, design

I've noticed that the tag badges don't align properly with the other badges, see screenshot:
[image]

Having seen tag badges on Stack Overflow and Super User, this shouldn't be the case.

Comment: You mean that circle thing? Those ribbons look like it makes them a larger image compared

Comment: I would expect those ribbons to appear on the tag badge. That would be a good suggestion as well in stead of having a different background color !!

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the circle just needs to be lined up with the ribbons. That will push the text a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling the tag badge, from a dark background to a white background, also resolved the misalignment of the badges.

[image]

**Case closed**